# How do I install Jenkins?

Tags: debian, raspbian, software-installation, java

I have installed Jenkins, using `sudo apt-get install jenkins` and it did not work immediately, so i worked out to increase the size of the `/run` tmpfs. Now I am still getting errors in my jenkins.log, and I cannot access the web interface.

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
14 Aug 2012 08:28:13 winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:185)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at Main._main(Main.java:285)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.13)
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:213)
   ...5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.util.DerValue not found in java.net.URLClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/winstone1fdfcs.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   ...7 more
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
14 Aug 2012 08:33:33 winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
14 Aug 2012 08:34:01 hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:264)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:107)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:875)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:87)
   at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:47)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:177)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at Main._main(Main.java:285)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.isOpenJDK(JVM.java:72)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.canUseSun14ReflectionProvider(JVM.java:198)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.bestReflectionProvider(JVM.java:175)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:431)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:73)
   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<clinit>(Jenkins.java:3510)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:264)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:107)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:875)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
14 Aug 2012 08:34:03 winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Error during context startup for webapp webapp
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:264)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:107)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:875)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:87)
   at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:47)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:177)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at Main._main(Main.java:285)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.isOpenJDK(JVM.java:72)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.canUseSun14ReflectionProvider(JVM.java:198)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.bestReflectionProvider(JVM.java:175)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:431)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:73)
   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<clinit>(Jenkins.java:3510)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:264)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:107)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:875)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
14 Aug 2012 08:34:03 winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8080
14 Aug 2012 08:34:03 winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Error during servlet context shutdown
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins.model.Jenkins
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:347)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.destroy(WebAppConfiguration.java:1149)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.destroyWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:148)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.destroy(HostConfiguration.java:156)
   at winstone.HostGroup.destroy(HostGroup.java:77)
   at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:337)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:199)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at Main._main(Main.java:285)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
14 Aug 2012 08:34:03 winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
14 Aug 2012 08:34:03 winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:185)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.13)
   at Main._main(Main.java:285)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.13)
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:213)
   ...5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.util.DerValue not found in java.net.URLClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/winstonepwah1w.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   ...7 more
```

**Additional information**

I do not have physical access to the pi for about 5 days, so I can't reinstall the OS or similar, however I do have VNC access and I can enable SSH if i need to.

I have rebooted the pi several times, and this did not fix the problem.

Comment: @ppumkin It did not show 8080 as an open port.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4487/discussion-between-bearbin-and-ppumkin)

Comment: Java does not run well on the pi - Jenkins is written in Java and expects "lots" of memory.

Comment: @bearbin How have you increased the /run partition?

Comment: @otakun85 I edited the `/etc/default/tmpfs` using `sudo nano /etc/default/tmpfs` then I changed the size under the `/run` part to about 40 MiB (This may not be completely correct, but I'm pretty sure it's right.)

Comment: @bearbin thanks. I found that this bug is already fixed in the current version of jenkins. I used the official "long" term support release package at http://jenkins-ci.org/ and installed it in the described Debian/Ubuntu way.

Comment: @otakun85 So there was a bug where Jenkins would eat /run? Or what are you talking about?

Comment: @bearbin yes. It's just the wrong directory to put the extraced war to. Thats why in the newer version they put that to /var/cache/jenkins/ . The bug was already fixed at the end of 2011. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11366

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From looking at the log file I came across the line

> INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8080
>
> java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener

This tells us that either the port you are using `8080` is in use but you have run [netstat](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/list-open-ports-and-listening-services/443) and established that it is not listed- so its available and not causing the exception.

Looking more closely the exception talks about `ssl.httplistener` - Jenkins requires Java version 6 or above and extra libraries to run.

So you should run the command `java -version`

```
java version 1.5.0 gij (GNU libgij)
```

If you get the above response then Jenkins will not start. That is because it does not support the official distribution of Java packed in mainstream Linux. It supports `OpenJDK` or `Sun-Java` ([Sun-Java is nearly supported on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1603/894))

You can resolve the issue by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

then chose `OpenJDK` followed by a reboot of the Pi.

Jenkins starts up as expected after boot.

*There was an initial high CPU load reported by the OP but he seems to be happy with the result in the end.*