# How can I get and install Oracle's Java JVM for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, java, hard-float, jvm

A recent [press release](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1735645) from Oracle suggests that they have just released a JVM for Raspbian. The key text is:

> Java SE 7 Update 6 introduces a JDK for Linux on ARM v6 and v7 to
>   address “general purpose” ARM systems, such as those used for the
>   emerging micro-server ARM market, and for development platforms such
>   as Raspberry Pi. This new JDK for Linux on ARM is made available under
>   the Oracle Binary Code License and is available for download at no
>   cost for development and production use on general-purpose platforms.

Have they really released a hard float JVM, and if so, how can I get it and install it on a Raspbian system?

Comment: `Redwood Shores, CA – August 14, 2012` : Very recent I'd say! I'll keep an eye on this :)

Comment: Note that you will want the small footprint JVM when it arrives - the Raspberry is a small device seen with Java eyes.

Comment: Possibly more important than the hard/soft float question is whether Oracle managed to get their JIT compiler working correctly on ARM.  Assuming you're not doing some serious maths I'd bet the jit compiler represents a larger performance increase than hardware float support.

Comment: It now looks as though the new developer preview of Java 8 _is_ hard float and does run on the pi! http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Developer-preview-of-Java-SE-8-for-ARM-now-available-1772644.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filename of the installer is jdk-7u6-linux-arm-**sfp**.tar.gz so it's soft-float and not hard-float.

Oracle states in this [press release](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/oracle_releases_jdk_for_linux):

> One caveat is that the current binary is softfloat ABI only, so it
>   won't work with (for example) the Raspbian distribution which uses the
>   hardfloat ABI. We are planning to add hardfloat support in an upcoming
>   JDK release, as well as support for JavaFX on ARM.

Comment: That is not the news I was hoping for... :-( Looking forward to the next release...

Comment: Will OpenSDK not suffice for you at the moment?

Comment: The OpenJDK works, but is _very_ slow, and the Cacao JIT is fundamentally broken. If performance isn't an issue, the plain OpenJDK is fine.

Comment: You can use the soft-float version with the e.g. Debian arm image. The overall Linux performance is worse, but the Java performance is significant better.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle have now released a developer preview of [Java 8](http://www.savagehomeautomation.com/projects/raspberry-pi-installing-oracle-java-se-8-with-javafx-develop.html) that works on the Raspberry Pi (hard-float)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle released the full Version (no longer preview) of Java 8 and Java 7 for the `ARM` architecture of the Raspberry Pi: [link to Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html).

You can also use from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk
```

Comment: This package does not exist in the current default Jessie repositories.